# Can't find e(fx)clipse plugin in Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm having an issue installing javafx, I already added User library and included all the jar files from javafx14.0.1 sdk folder and provided  `--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` in VM arguments but new error occurred when I ran the program  `it says Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw`
`Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found`
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found` etc.

so I'm assuming maybe I need to install e(fx)clipse plugin in eclipse, because that is the only solution that I have never tried that I found online for installing javafx in eclipse.

by the way I'm using JDK 12 and Eclipse 2018-09.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the instructions here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/
You don't need e(fx)clipse to run JavaFX apps from Eclipse.
Update your ancient software stack. We are writing the year 2020.

Comment: I updated my eclipse IDE I'm now using the latest version of it but still Eclipse 2020-06 with e(fx)clipse plugin and I'm using JDK 12, I followed also the step but still I'm receiving those errors.

Comment: 1. As you are already past JDK 11 it does not make sense to stick to JDK 12. You could also use the latest JDK 14.0.2. 2. Which platform are you using? Does a simple JavaFX program run from the command line?

Comment: I see, so I need to update also my JDK, but from what I read online JavaFX 14 is working fine with JDK11 to latest so I assumed JDK 12 would work but I will update my JDK and see if that would work. I've never tried yet to run the project through command line I'm just using Eclipse IDE but I will try that too, run the project through the command line.